# Issue With setting tag for Button UITableView

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4

I have two buttons inside sectioned tableview cell thumbs up and thumbs down. Initially image of both button is not selected. When I select thumbs up button its image become thumbs up selected and other one become thumbsdown not selected and vice versa.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
{
    NSLog(@"mod:numberOfSectionsInTableView");
    NSLog(@"[preferences count]=%d",[preferences count]);
    return  [preferences count];
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.choices count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexpath
{
    NSLog(@"cellForRowAtIndexPath: DISPLAY TEST");  
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        NSLog(@"Text is: %@", [choices objectAtIndex:indexpath.row]);                   
        NSLog(@"CHOICE AT INDEX PATH IS: %@",[choices objectAtIndex:indexpath.row %[choices count]]);
        cell.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];


        // Thumbs up button.
        //UIButton *thumbsUp = [[UIButton alloc]init];  
        thumbsUp = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];                        
        [thumbsUp setTag:(indexpath.row+(indexpath.section * 50))];
        [thumbsUp addTarget:self action:@selector(thumbUp_ButtonClicked:event:)
            forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];     
        [thumbsUp setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        thumbsUp.frame = CGRectMake(150.0, 20, 20, 15);
        [thumbsUp setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"thumbsup_not_selected.png"]
     forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        //NSLog(@"------------------>TAG TEST : %d",(indexpath.row+(indexpath.section * 50)));
        [cell.contentView addSubview:thumbsUp];

        // Thumbs down button

        thumbsDown = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [thumbsDown addTarget:self  action:@selector(thumbDown_ButtonClicked:event:)
            forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [thumbsDown setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        thumbsDown.frame = CGRectMake(200, 20, 20, 15);

        [thumbsDown setTag:indexpath.row+120];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:thumbsDown];
        [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];


        [thumbsDown setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"thumbsdown_not_selected.png"]
            forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

    NSLog(@"------------> TAG TEST %d",thumbsUp.tag);
    cell.text = [choices objectAtIndex:(indexpath.row % [choices count])];


    NSLog(@"HELLO FOR TESTING");
    return cell;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSString *sectionTitle = [self tableView:tableView titleForHeaderInSection:section];
    if (sectionTitle == nil) {
        return nil;
    }

    // Create label with section title
    UILabel *label = [[[UILabel alloc] init] autorelease];
    label.frame = CGRectMake(15, 10, 300, 25);
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    label.shadowColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    label.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 1.0);
    label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
    label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    label.text = sectionTitle;


    // Create header view and add label as a subview
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12, 0, 300, 60)];
    [view autorelease];
    [view addSubview:label];
    //[view addSubview:segmentedControl];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    return view;
}

//Thumbs Up Button Action

- (IBAction)thumbUp_ButtonClicked:(id)sender event:(id)event
{
    NSLog(@"Thumbs Up Check!");


    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *) [[button superview] superview];


    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [myTable indexPathForCell:cell];
    NSLog(@"indexpath =%d",indexPath.row);
    //[button setTag:indexPath.row+(indexPath.section * 50)];

    int cTag = [sender tag];
    NSLog(@"------>TAG : %d", cTag);
    NSLog(@"------> Calculated TAG %d",indexPath.row+(indexPath.section * 50));
    if(cTag == (indexPath.row+(indexPath.section * 50)))
    {
        NSLog(@"BUTTON COUNT:");
        [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"thumbsup_selected.png"]
            forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }


    NSInteger section = indexPath.section;
    NSInteger row = indexPath.row;

    //int row = button.tag;

    NSLog(@"SECTION IS:%d",section);
    NSLog(@"ROW IS: %d",row);


    NSArray *array = cell.contentView.subviews;
    NSLog(@"NUMBER OF OBJECTS: %d",[array count]);
    UIButton *test = (UIButton *)[array objectAtIndex:2];

    [test setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"thumbsdown_not_selected.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
```

Due to issue with tag of button while I change image of one button several buttons are changing. If any one can please find a solution it will be helpful.... tag is setting for buttons in sections which we can view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corrected the issue by creating buttons outside and inside if(cell == nil). Also created a mutable dictionary to keep the current state of the button.....

Comment: Which is bad practice too, because when the cells are recycled/reuse you will recreate a button that already exist, and after scrolling a lot you will end having a lot of useless buttons in the same cell (all the buttons being at the exact same position and size, thus only the last one added being visible, but still wasting a lot of memory and rendering time). Again, go read the Table View Programming Guide where everything is explained, as your solution only hides the problem but does not solve it

Answer (score 2):

The reason is the bad use of the recycling/reuse mechanism (as with 75% of questions about UITableView…)

Go read the Table View Programming Guide in Apple's doc (and search SO and the web for any question related to tableview and the reuse mechanism)